# Multiclient udp server handling error code 10054 properly

Tags: c#, sockets, error-handling, udp

I've got an UDP server which can handle multiple clients, Now the main thing about UDP is that it is connection less so i was quite suprised when i got the following error:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I quickly learned this was because I was trying to send to an IPEndpoint which was closed. Later I learned this was because the network layer would send back an ICMP message saying the port was closed and the ICMP message is why the error is thrown. Now obviously I started to look for solutions for this problem but, although I've found many questions about this on stack overflow, I could not find one with a correct answer. (some even have 0 answers).

When I got this error i wouldn't receive anything anymore because my `BeginReceiveFrom` method was in the try part after the exception was thrown. I then placed it in the catch part as well but this would simply result in the same error being thrown again.

so the problem, once the error: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." is thrown I cannot use the socket anymore (or so it seems to me)

and my question is: how do i handle this exception so my server can keep running?

This is my code:

```
public void Listen()
{
    if (mDisposing == true)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, "This instance is already disposed");
    }

    if (mListening == false)
    {
        try
        {
            mListening = true;
            ServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ServerAddress, Port);
            mServerSocket = new Socket(ServerAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            mServerSocket.Bind(ServerEndPoint);

            if (ServerAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
                Version version = os.Version;

                // NOTE: Windows Vista or higher have one IP stack for IPv4 and IPv6
                // Therefore they can be combined and used as one socket for IPv6
                // The socket must then accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections.
                if (version.Major > 5)
                {
                    // NOTE: IPV6_V6ONLY socket option is equivalent to 27 in the winsock snippet below
                    // This is available in Framework 4.0. A lower version can implement (SocketOptionName)27
                    mServerSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, 0);
                }
            }

            var ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var endPointSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
            mServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(mByteData, 0, mByteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref endPointSender, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            mListening = false;
            DoError(exception);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        var endPointSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
        mServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(mByteData, 0, mByteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref endPointSender, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), null);
    }
}

public void Close()
{
    if (mDisposing == true)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, "This instance is already disposed");
    }

    if (mListening == true)
    {
        mListening = false;

        try
        {
            foreach (ClientInformation client in mClients)
            {
                Disconnect(client.ID);
            }

            if (mServerSocket != null)
            {
                mServerSocket.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            DoError(exception);
        }
    }
}

private void WaitForData()
{
    if (mListening == true)
    {
        try
        {
            var ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var endPointSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
            mServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(mByteData, 0, mByteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref endPointSender, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            DoError(exception);
        }
    }
}

private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    if (mListening == true)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            EndPoint remoteEndPoint = ipeSender;

            int iRx = mServerSocket.EndReceiveFrom(asyncResult, ref remoteEndPoint);
            var clientInfo = new ClientInformation(remoteEndPoint);

            mClients.Add(clientInfo);

            var chars = new byte[iRx];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(mByteData, 0, chars, 0, iRx);
            WaitForData();
            DoReceived(clientInfo, chars);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            WaitForData();
            DoError(exception);
        }
    }
}

public void Send(string remoteEndPoint, byte[] data)
{
    if (mListening == true)
    {
        var clientInfo = ActiveConnections.Find(remoteEndPoint);
        if (clientInfo != null)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (LockSend)
                {
                    clientInfo.DataOut = data;
                    mServerSocket.BeginSendTo(
                        clientInfo.DataOut,
                        0,
                        clientInfo.DataOut.Length,
                        SocketFlags.None,
                        clientInfo.RemoteEndPoint,
                        new AsyncCallback(OnDataSent),
                        clientInfo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                DoError(exception);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mLogger.ErrorFormat("Trying to send to client {0} which does not exist", remoteEndPoint);
        }
    }
}

private void OnDataSent(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    if (mListening == true)
    {
        var clientInfo = (ClientInformation)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            lock (LockSend)
            {
                int iRx = mServerSocket.EndSendTo(asyncResult);
                if (iRx == clientInfo.DataOut.Length)
                {
                    byte[] chars = new byte[iRx];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(clientInfo.DataOut, 0, chars, 0, iRx);
                    DoSent(clientInfo, chars);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            DoError(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

I am happy to provide extra information when needed and am hoping this problem can be resolved.

The error description as provided by microsoft:

> WSAECONNRESET 10054 Connection reset by peer. An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the
>   peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is
>   rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the
>   remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on
>   the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result
>   if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a
>   failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that
>   were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail
>   with WSAECONNRESET.

Comment: Can you shorten the code? Probably 5x shortening is required. Closing for now.

Comment: @usr how do you want me to shorten it? remove the comments/documentation?

Comment: Everything that's unnecessary to demonstrate the problem. Frankly, many won't read all of this. No need to look at things like `public IPAddress Address
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ServerAddress;
        }
    }`.

Comment: @usr Ok I've shortened it to only the meaning full methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to find a fix for this namely the following code:

```
var sioUdpConnectionReset = -1744830452;
var inValue = new byte[] { 0 };
var outValue = new byte[] { 0 };
mServerSocket.IOControl(sioUdpConnectionReset, inValue, outValue);
```

By my knowledge it simply suppresses the error, I had to implement this in my Listen method which now looks like this:

```
public void Listen()
{
    if (mDisposing == true)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, "This instance is already disposed");
    }

    if (mListening == false)
    {
        try
        {
            mListening = true;
            ServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ServerAddress, Port);
            mServerSocket = new Socket(ServerAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            var sioUdpConnectionReset = -1744830452;
            var inValue = new byte[] { 0 };
            var outValue = new byte[] { 0 };
            mServerSocket.IOControl(sioUdpConnectionReset, inValue, outValue);

            mServerSocket.Bind(ServerEndPoint);

            if (ServerAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
                Version version = os.Version;

                // NOTE: Windows Vista or higher have one IP stack for IPv4 and IPv6
                // Therefore they can be combined and used as one socket for IPv6
                // The socket must then accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections.
                if (version.Major > 5)
                {
                    // NOTE: IPV6_V6ONLY socket option is equivalent to 27 in the winsock snippet below
                    // This is available in Framework 4.0. A lower version can implement (SocketOptionName)27
                    mServerSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, 0);
                }
            }

            var ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var endPointSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
            mServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(mByteData, 0, mByteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref endPointSender, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            mListening = false;
            DoError(exception);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        var endPointSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
        mServerSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(mByteData, 0, mByteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref endPointSender, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), null);
    }
}
```